# Android usb device set baud rate

Tags: android, usb

How can I manually set baud rate 57600 to my usb connection? I try to do it like this:

```
UsbConnector connector = new UsbConnector(getApplicationContext(), device, listener);
if (device != null) {
    connector.run();
    UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
    usbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);// reset
    usbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 1, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Rx
    usbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 2, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Tx
    usbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x0034, 0, null, 0, 0);//Baud rate 57600)


    connector.send(pal);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] received = connector.receive(36);
    if (received == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Błąd inicjalizacji skanera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work - received is `null`. Any help please?

Comment: try this: usbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03, 49204, 0, null, 0, 0);
it's complicated to explain how i got that value, but that's how they set it in this repo and it seems to work: https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleUsbTerminal